# How do I interpret the order that an $p$-adic $L$-series vanishes to?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I know how to find the the order of vanishing for a complex $L$-series $L(E,1)$.

I'm looking at an example:

$\mathcal{L}_7(E,T)=O(7^9)+O(7^6)T+(6\cdot7^5+O(7^6))T^2+(3\cdot7^5+O(7^6))T^3+(5+5\cdot7+2\cdot7^4+7^5+O(7^6))T^4+O(T^5)$

How do I tell that the $L$-series vanishes to order 7?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to figure out what $T$ means.  Often (indeed, typically) for $p$-adic $L$-functions,
$T$ denotes an element in the Iwasawa algebra, chosen so that the Iwasawa algebra
equals $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$, and then there is a change of variables to relate
this to the classical $s$ variable, e.g. of the form $T = (1+p)^{s-1} - 1.$

But different people use different conventions, and you will have to figure out
what conventions your example is using.

Let's suppose, though, that it is the one I gave, so that $s = 1$ corresponds to $T  = 0$.  Then your example certainly doesn't vanish to order $7$.  Indeed, it has a non-zero coefficient of $T^2$, and may possibly have a non-zero constant term or non-zero coefficient of $T$ as well (the information you give isn't dispositive on this).

So the order of vanishing is at most $2$.

On the other hand, if the convention for relating $T$ and $s$ is different, e.g. if $T = (1+p)^{s} - 1,$ then you would have to compute the order of vanishing at $T = 7$, and this would be different.  (Although since you don't have terms all the way up to degree $7$, even if the order of vanishing was $7$, I don't think you would be able to see that with the degree of approximation you have.)

One more thing: it's pretty hard to find elliptic curves of rank $7$, so I would be surprised if you really had an $L$-function that had that much vanishing at $s = 1$.  But they do exist, so maybe you've found one!

Oh, and for background, the paper of Mazur and Swinnerton-Dyer is still pretty good.

Comment: Hmm. That's exactly what I thought as well initially when I was looking at the paper that gave this example. But then this was the only example given in the paper so there was no way I could verify whether I'm right. I will check with the authors.

Comment: @HaikalYeo: What paper did this come from?  (I'm curious to look myself now.)

Comment: http://wstein.org/papers/shark/shark.pdf bottom of page 31.